# how to convert timestamp to date in android?

Tags: java, android, timestamp

i have a time stamp coming in my XML that i put into my database.

The time stamp is in the format of number of seconds gone by since 1970.
i want to convert that into a date object.

how do i go about it?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a `Date` instance based on the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970. Your value is expressed in seconds, but that a trivial conversion:

```
 long timestamp = getTimestampInSeconds();  // some megic to get the value
 Date date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);    // convert to milliseconds
```

Answer (score 2):

Date class has special constructor for this:

```
Date result = new Date(numberOfSec * 1000);
```

Further you can format your `Date` object as you like using `SimpleDateFormat`.

See the [doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29).

Comment: you have to check out the api: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

It's been awhile since the question been asked, but i just faced the same trouble. 
And I found out that the trouble is in the variable type. Are you using integer to store the timestamp value? Try using long. It worked for me